# MongoDB Node.js each method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, limit, each

I have an array of data which I'll store in the database. When I'm looking if the data already exists, each() will called twice, even when I'm using limit(1). I have no clue whats going on here...

```
collection.find({
    month: 'april'
}).limit(1).count(function(err, result){
    console.log('counter', result);
});

collection.find({
    month: 'april'
}).limit(1).each(function(err, result){
    console.log('each', result);
});

collection.find({
    month: 'april'
}).limit(1).toArray(function(err, result){
    console.log('toArray', result);
});
```

At this time, there is exact 1 dataset of month April already stored in the collection.
The above queries will generate an output like this:

```
count 1
each {...}
each null
toArray {...}
```

In the mongo shell I have checked the count() and forEach() methods. Everything works as expected. Is it a driver problem? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Can you `console.log` the `err` variable in your each iteration just to see what it is the second time thru?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. The driver returns the items in the loop, and then at the end it returns `null` to indicate that there are no items left. You can see this in the driver's [examples](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/examples/cursor.js#L21-L24) too:

```
// Find returns a Cursor, which is Enumerable. You can iterate:
collection.find().each(function(err, item) {
  if(item != null) console.dir(item);
});
```

If you are interested in the details, you can check the [source code](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/1.4/lib/mongodb/cursor.js#L235-L252) for `each`:

```
if(this.items.length > 0) {
  // Trampoline all the entries
  while(fn = loop(self, callback)) fn(self, callback);
  // Call each again
  self.each(callback);
} else {
  self.nextObject(function(err, item) {

    if(err) {
      self.state = Cursor.CLOSED;
      return callback(utils.toError(err), item);
    }

>>  if(item == null) return callback(null, null);  <<
    callback(null, item);
    self.each(callback);
  })
}
```

In this code `each` iterates through the items using `loop` which shifts items from the array (`var doc = self.items.shift();`). When `this.items.length` becomes `0`, the else block is executed. This else block tries to get the next document from the cursor. If there are no more documents, `nextObject` returns `null` (`item`'s value becomes `null`) which makes `if(item == null) return callback(null, null);` to be executed. As you can see the callback is called with `null`, and this is the `null` that you can see in the console.

This is needed because MongoDB returns the matching documents using a [cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/). If you have millions of documents in the collection and you run `find()`, not all documents are returned immediately because you would run out of memory. Instead MongoDB iterates through the items using a cursor. "For most queries, the first batch returns 101 documents or just enough documents to exceed 1 megabyte." So `this.items.length` becomes the number of the items that are in the first batch, but that's not necessarily the total number of the documents resulted by the query. That's why when you iterate through the documents and `this.items.length` becomes 0, MongoDB uses the cursor to check if there are more matching documents. If there are, it loads the next batch, otherwise it returns `null`.

It's easier to understand this if you use a large limit. For example in case of `limit(100000)` you would need a lot of memory if MongoDB returned all 100000 documents immediately. Not to mention how slow processing would be. Instead, MongoDB returns results in batches. Let's say the first batch contains 101 documents. Then `this.items.length` becomes 101, but that's only the size of the first batch, not the total number of the result. When you iterate through the results and you reach the next item after the last one that is in the current batch (102nd in this case), MongoDB uses the cursor to check if there are more matching documents. If there are, the next batch of documents are loaded, `null` otherwise.

But you don't have to bother with `nextObject()` in you code, you only need to check for `null` as in the MongoDB example.

Comment: But why it's needed to check for a nextObject when this.items.length == 0? This should implicate that item == null, isn't it?

Comment: Extended my answer. It only makes sense if the result contains a lot of documents. In case of `limit(1)` it's easy to tell that there are no more items. But `each` has to be consistent, that's why it always returns `null` after the last item.

Comment: Ok, I understood it now, thank you. I guess, each() is not the right function to check if a document already exists, right? Thats why findOne() exists? In the case of checking for null, I'll get wrong results because it returns null, if there are no matched documents in that collection yet and it returns null, if the document exists and the end of the collection has reached.

Comment: `each()` is used to iterate through the items that are returned by `find()`. It is useful when you expect the query to return more documents. If you just want to check the existence of a document, then using `findOne()` is the easiest. It returns `null` if the item doesn't exist. You can use a code like this: `collection.findOne({}, function(err, item) { if (!err && item != null) { // exists } }`